# model binders for complex types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following model:

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
        public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

where Address is:

```
public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create a form/view, I have created the view :

Create

```
<div>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="FirstName" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="LastName" />
</div>

 <div>
    <label>Billing Address</label>
    <input name="BillingAddress" />
</div>

 <div>
    <label>Shipping Address</label>
    <input name="ShippingAddress" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>

</form>
```

I want to show full address, I mean city and street. Do I need to create partial view or what? I need to post this view to following actionResult:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Customer customerToCreate)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Please suggest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, override ToString() on Address:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public override ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}",Street,City);
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
@model Customer

<div>
    <label>First Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor<Customer,string>(m => m.Firstname)
</div>

<div>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor<Customer,string>(m => m.Firstname)
</div>

<div>
    <label>Billing Address</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor<Customer,string>(m => m.BillingAddress)
</div>

<div>
    <label>Shipping Address</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor<Customer,string>(m => m.ShippingAddress)
    <input name="ShippingAddress" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
```

Comment: cant I do it without using strongly type model ? I mean without  @Html.TextBoxFor<Customer,string>(m => m.ShippingAddress). I have created a partial view for address and used it but the post create method doesnt get the address values

Answer (score 0):

create strongly typed view. type of Customer.